# What HTTP status should I return during temporary site outage/downtime?

Tags: apache-2.2, http, outage

I'm going to be taking down my website for an upgrade to the code.  I'd like to have a temporary downtime page display during the upgrade.  For the sake of preventing issues with bots attempting to spider my site during the downtime, what HTTP response should I make sure to return during this window?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the RFC, the correct response to return is [503 - Service Unavailable](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

> 10.5.4 503 Service Unavailable
>
> **The server is currently unable to**
>   **handle the request due to** a temporary
>   overloading or **maintenance of the**
>   **server**. The implication is that this
>   is a temporary condition which will be
>   alleviated after some delay. If known,
>   the length of the delay MAY be
>   indicated in a Retry-After header. If
>   no Retry-After is given, the client
>   SHOULD handle the response as it would
>   for a 500 response.
>
> ```
>   Note: The existence of the 503 status code does not imply that a
>   server must use it when becoming overloaded. Some servers may wish
>   to simply refuse the connection.
> ```

Comment: I'd upmod your response, but I'm not at 15 rep yet. You've got the checkmark though. :) Thank you!

Comment: No problem..   :)